# Expected value of a series

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, borel-cantelli-lemmas

While learning about the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, I came across [this article](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2015/2dc1c9e37d402c000b628ee85e2228d1_MIT18_304S15_project2.pdf) and I am having trouble following the Introduction. I cite the relevant text here:

> Consider an infinite sequence of games, where in game $n$ one loses $2^n$
> dollars with probability $\frac{1}{2^n+1}$ and win a dollar with probability $\frac{2^n}{2^n+1}$.
> Even though the expected value is 0, for all $n$, if we sum over $n$ the
> probability that a person will lose in game $n$, we will find the total
> number of expected losses. For example, if we take the integral from 0
> to infinity for $\frac{1}{2^n+1}dn$ , we will find that
> $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+1}dn=1$.
> We expect to lose a single time, even though we play into infinity and there always exists a non-zero probability of losing.

My reasoning to find the expected number of losses would be:

Let $X_n$ be the result in a game $n$ where $X_n=1$ if it is a loss and 0 if it is a win. Then define $Y_n$ as the number of losses for $n$ games. If we then want to find the expected number of losses in infinite games: $\lim_{n\to\infty}E[Y_n] = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{1}^{n}E[X_n] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n+1}$ .

That would have been my reasoning, to apply the linearity of expectations.

So first of all I don't know where my reasoning fails and second, I do not understand the integral in the quoted text nor its meaning. Could you please help me understand?

Comment: Well, I imagine they mean the sum when they write the integral ($dn$ is a measure with atoms at each natural number).  But $\sum \frac 1{2^n+1}$ is not $1$.

Comment: Perhaps they are using the integral as a way to estimate the series.  the series sums to about $.7645$ which is even less than $1$, so the point they are trying to make seems valid...on it's face it seems paradoxical that you expect to lose less than  once and yet you also expect to earn $0$ playing the game infinitely often.

Comment: You are right, they use the integral just to give an upper bound and show the convegence, thanks. On the other hand, I guess the unintuitive point about how when using linearity of expectations you would get  a profit of 0 and the Borel-Cantelli lemma says you would have infinite profit, the thing is that you can not apply linearity of expectations here since the series does not converge absolutely i.e. $\sum_{1}^\infty E|profit_i| = \infty$.

Comment: The way the integral is taken in this article is trivially incorrect; you cannot writhe things like  $\infty-\infty$, so I would be cautious using this article!